# VSC path intellisense does not work properly

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, directory, path

My problem is that i can't see the files while i'm using VS Code intellisense for path exploration.
Here's an example of my problem
[Example of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEUQZ.gif)

#### White Space in Names

I thought it was a problem realted to white space in the name of the folders so I tried a few things. At the end I discovered that names with white space stop intellisense only if I'm using the absolute path (starting with 'C://') while it still works if I'm using the relative path ('./').

Do you know if this behavior is a bug or a wanted feature? Do you know how to fix this?
I'd really need to see my files both with relative and absolute paths.

If you need any other kind of info comment below and I will edit the post.

#### WME

Open a python file in VSC.
Choose a destination file and be sure that the path contains a folder with white space in it. If you don't have any just create one.
Start typing

```
'C://Users/[username]/[your path with whitespace]/ '
```

After the first whitespace folder press `ctrl+spacebar` to show suggestions, the problem is that no suggestions appear.
Now retry using the relative path.
Start typing

```
'../[your path with whitespace]/ '
```

press `ctrl+bar` and look at the suggestions that should now appear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function in jupyter, at `.py` files have no intellisense about file paths yet.

Regarding absolute and relative paths, you can right-click on the file in vscode and select **Copy Path** or **Copy Relative Path**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not answering my question. You are telling me how to copy a path from VSC. I'm asking how to automatically complete paths using Intellisense after a white space. (watching the [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEUQZ.gif) in the post may prove useful)

Comment: Currently it is not possible to use intellisense for paths in python files(Available in jupyter). As for the whitespace issue, this should be a bug to be fixed.